# Implementing a DBAppender for logback to insert logs into a CouchDB

Tags: java, logging, couchdb, slf4j, logback

I need to be able to implement a DBAppender for logback to write event logs into a CouchDB using Java. For a conventional Relational DB, this is done by extending DBAppenderBase. Does anyone know how to do this in CouchDB with Java? Thanks!

Comment: The idea is great! I guess you are not going to store logs for ages. But CouchDB does not deletes documents, it just marks them as deleted.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, i'm new to CouchDB and glad you pointed out that aspect to consider. I believe you can accomplish this by doing a compact on the db after the deleting operation to purge stale data away.

Comment: Here’s [a blog post about a logback appender for MongoDB](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.de/2011/04/mongodb-and-recording-appenders-for.html) you could get some ideas from.

Comment: I had similar problem in the past but for mongoDB. You can have a look here https://github.com/kofemann/mongo-appender-for-logback

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Logback Appender implementation for MongoDB](https://github.com/exacode/logback-extensions) on GitHub.